# How to insert data's in SQL server using soap web service in android

Tags: android, soap, insert

How to insert data in SQL server table using soap web service in android,I create a android application using Geo code,It shows the place,city name,zip code and state.

please tell how to store all the data's in SQL server using soap web service in android.I know the retrieving concept but i didn't know how to insert..

Please help 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you need a web-service for this,send your data with appropriate parameters with get or post method whichever method web-service accepts,then the server will accept the data and insert into database you just need to send the data in required and correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.
From my experienece, I used ksoap2 web service and .net c# webservice.

```
public final boolean sendGeoMethod(String strCity, String strName, String strZipCode, String strState)
{
    soapSendGeoMethod = NAMESPACE + "/" + methodGeoMethod;

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 200000);
    boolean isValid = false;
    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE + "/", methodGeoMethod);
        //Property Name should be same as your webservice's parameter names
        request.addProperty("strCity", strCity);
        request.addProperty("strName", strName);
        request.addProperty("strZipCode", strZipCode);
        request.addProperty("strState", strState);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        androidHttpTransport.call(soapSendGeoMethod, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse(); //Get XML Result

        isValid = Boolean.valueOf(result.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        isValid = false;            
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Be sure you have included INTERNET permission in your manifest: 
     `< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

You place your insert SQL statement in your web service.